# Rows in Sections count not updating in TableView

Tags: uitableview, core-data, xcode6, swift2

I'm having a hard time when I have an item in my UITableView and I update the attribute value that determines the Section.

I have figured out it has something to do with didChangeSection and the option NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update. But that is as far as I'm able to get.

I'm not sure what code I need to put in there that would update the number of rows in a section.

This is the exact error code I'm getting:

> 2016-04-17 20:00:37.126 EZ List[13722:1469523] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716
>   2016-04-17 20:00:37.126 EZ List[13722:1469523] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

And this is the code in my view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
var list: Lists?
var catalog: Catalog?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.title = list?.name

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TableBackground"))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.name
    }

    return nil

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 200/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 0.5)
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    //header.alpha = 0.5 //make the header transparent

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listContentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemsTableViewCell
    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 78, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    cell.itemName.text = item.name
    cell.itemSection.text = item.section
    cell.itemQty.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!)"
    cell.itemSize.text = item.size
    cell.itemPrice.text = floatToCurrency(Float(item.cost!))
    cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
    cell.itemID.text = String(item.id!)

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

        // Code to come

    }

    let qty = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Qty") { (action, indexPath) in

        // Code to come

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 84/255, green: 200/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)

    return [delete, edit, qty]

}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.endUpdates()

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ListItemsTableViewCell
        let item = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Items

        cell.itemName.text = item.name
        cell.itemSection.text = item.section
        cell.itemQty.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!)"
        cell.itemSize.text = item.size
        cell.itemPrice.text = floatToCurrency(Float(item.cost!))
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
        cell.itemID.text = String(item.id!)
    default:
        print("didChangeObject Default was accessed")
        break
    }

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        print("didChangeSection Default was accessed")
        break
    }

}

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isChecked", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2, sortDesc3]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "section" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func getCatalog(id: NSNumber) -> Catalog {

    var cat: Catalog?

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Catalog")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id", id)
    fetchReq.predicate = pred

    do {
        let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        cat = (check.first as! Catalog)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed fetching Catalog Entry matching Item")
    }

    return cat!
}

func floatToCurrency(flt: Float) -> String {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    return String(formatter.stringFromNumber(flt)!)

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var id: NSNumber

    if (segue.identifier == "listItemView") {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let itemCont: ViewItemViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewItemViewController
        let item: Items = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Items
        itemCont.item = item
        id = item.id!
        itemCont.catalog = getCatalog(id)
    } else if (segue.identifier == "listItemViewEdit") {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        let itemCont: AddItemListViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddItemListViewController
        let item: Items = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Items
        itemCont.item = item
        id = item.id!
        itemCont.catalog = getCatalog(id)
        itemCont.list = list
    }

}

}
```

I feel like I'm really close to getting it right, but I just need that extra push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't a problem with didChangeSection and NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update. It was a problem with didChangeObject and NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move.

The following code fixed my issue. Everything else is the same, so I'll just put those two functions.

Added NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move and inside it I delete the old location and and the new location.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    /*case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)*/
    default:
        print("didChangeSection Default was accessed")
        break
    }

}
```

Removed NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update since the move takes care of the Section updating.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! ListItemsTableViewCell
        let item = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Items

        cell.itemName.text = item.name
        cell.itemSection.text = item.section
        cell.itemQty.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!)"
        cell.itemSize.text = item.size
        cell.itemPrice.text = floatToCurrency(Float(item.cost!))
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
        cell.itemID.text = String(item.id!)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

}
```

Hopes this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the rows in the update you are talking about and check this if it helps 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12184

Comment: So you think that its not a problem with my code, but instead a problem with Xcode?

Comment: Maybe Yes ,that's what the thread said ,  try to check with breakpoints how many times the delegate method fires and upon updating ,inserting or deleting which of the  NSFetchedResultsChangeType executes .First try reloading the rows .